# Sign in twitter app for any users (Twython)

Tags: authentication, python-3.x, twitter, twython

I create desktop application to work with twitter.
To Authentication in my twitter app I use this code:

```
APP_KEY = '...from my app'
APP_SECRET = '...from my app'
OAUTH_TOKEN = '...from my app'
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = '...from my app'

twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
```

How other users can Sign in my desktop application? How to implement this with Twython?

Comment: You need to provide more information...  How are you receiving input on your desktop application?  Do you want them to provide their tokens or do you want to retrieve it based on user screen name and password?  Much more information is necessary.

Comment: @mbeacom Thanks for your feedback!
I want to use some secure method to sing in my desktop application.
Other API which use Oauth 1.0 provide sing in method with login in browser window and verifier code, but I couldn't find something like this for Twython and twitter. :(